# Clean URL's not respected on local

Tags: .htaccess

I have set up my Apache 2.4 on this new Yosemite machine to use vhosts but the clean urls are yielding 404s. The .htaccess works on the 1and1 server and I'm using it in this folder. Reading other SO posts say to enable mod-rewrite and AllowOverride All which I believe I have done. Here is my [vhost configuration](https://gist.github.com/sam452/63af7a51c130cd27e56f)

This is my [working .htaccess](https://gist.github.com/sam452/103e090c1ac1d59df2bc) that production uses:
For more clarity this is the output of apachectl -M

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
```

I have moved the application folder into OS X webserver and commented out the vhost include statement to ensure that if there is an issue with my vhost it should show up. However, there is a 404 response when drilling down to /user.

What am I overlooking? thx, sam

Comment: Is mod rewrite listed in `apachectl -M`?

Comment: It appears so according to the output above. THX.

Answer (score 3):

It may be that your Apache vhost and/or .htaccess need updating.

Yosemite uses Apache 2.4, which replaces some access control statements used in 2.2 and prior.

'Allow from all' becomes 'Require all granted'

'Deny from all' becomes 'Require all denied'

See [htaccess protections do not work on Apache 2.4 without mod_access_compat](https://www.drupal.org/node/1599774) for the ongoing Drupal 7 core discussion. [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) gives some guidance on upgrading configurations.

Comment: This is true. I only see it in line 6 which is the Order directive for FilesMatch. Reading on the docs this syntax seems to be allowed but what should it be if this is the root of my problem? thx